# Log errors in online projects

Tags: php, html, error-handling

what is a good method to log errors when it comes to bigger web projects?

I'm soon to be running a site with a main site, a shop and some subdomains (HTML/PHP) and would like to know when anything is not working especially in the checkout and payment process of the shop.

A simple 404 is not enough to track where the error happend, right?

Thanks for inspiration.
Frank

Answer (score 1):

you can log all transactions in the database whether their successful or not and then generate reports accordingly. here I'm talking about CC errors and insufficient funds issues.

for the actual errors(warnings, notices and fatal ones) do not display errors on production server because it might facilitate your website being hacked. instead configure your .ini files to log errors in log files.

php.ini
mysql slow queries 
httpd.conf